# Saving files names in a txt file with Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a directory with many files and I would like to save the name of these files in a txt document. I am going to do it with a few directories so I want to add the names below But with the code created, I delete the files already saved by the new ones.

This is my code:

```
os.chdir("/Users/Desktop/Data")

a = open("Names_Genomes.txt", "w")

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/Desktop/control/input/end'):
    for filename in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

And I also save the directory but I do not want this.

```
/Users/Desktop/control/input/end/SRR3160442_bin.7.fna
/Users/Desktop/control/input/end/SRR1039533_bin.14.fna
/Users/Desktop/control/input/end/SRR6257496_bin.3.fna
/Users/Desktop/control/input/end/ERR1305905_bin.7.fna
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `a.writelines(s + "\n" for s in files)`

Comment: If "a few directories" means you will be using different directories for `os.walk(r'/Users/Desktop/control/input/end')` and don't want to delete then you would need to open text file in append mode i.e. a = open("Names_Genomes.txt", "a+").  Also consider using a "with block" as in `with open("Names_Genomes.txt", "a+') as a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to save the files names not the absolute file path, you must remove the line:

```
f = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

The final code must be something like:

```
os.chdir("/Users/Desktop/Data")

a = open("Names_Genomes.txt", "w")

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/Desktop/control/input/end'):
    for filename in files:
        a.write(str(filename) + os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to write only the filename, you should remove the join to the absolute path. Just do the following:

```
os.chdir("/Users/Desktop/Data")

a = open("Names_Genomes.txt", "a")

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/Desktop/control/input/end'):
    for filename in files:
        a.write(filename + os.linesep)
```

Keep in mind that I changed the mode in the `open()` command to `a` instead of 'w' which will not overwrite you data but will append it.

Answer (score 0):

**Saving files names from 2 directories ,side by side in a txt file with Python**

import os

```
path="/content/HRNet-Semantic-Segmentation/imgs/images"  
path2 ="/content/HRNet-Semantic-Segmentation/imgs/masks"

a = open("/content/train.txt", "w")
    
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            f = os.path.join(path, filename)
    
        for filename2 in files:
            f2 = os.path.join(path2, filename2)
    
            a.write(str(f+" "+f2) + os.linesep)
```

**output:**

```
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_7150.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_13645.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_4635.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_8510.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_5720.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_13820.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_7675.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_4765.jpg
/content/imgs/images/frame_7450.jpg /content/imgs/masks/frame_7715.jpg
```